# rails 3 jquery ajax partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have read multiple tutorials where a partial is rendered as `render @products`, and then if you ajax a form for a new product, in the .js file you can do a `render @product` render the new product on the page.

However this only works if the view folder you are working in is called `products`, else you have to render the partial via `render :partial => 'product', :collection => @products`.  Then when I want to ajax a form, I am unable to just append the new product with `render :partial => 'product', :collection => @product`. I have to clear the div and render all of the products again.

Is there a way to just render the new product, rather than having to clear and re-render all of the products when not working in a view folder with the same name as the model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my controller, I had to add

`class PostController < ApplicationController`
     `respond_to :html, :js`

then

`def add`
  `@post = Post.new(params[:post])`
  `if @post.save`
     `respond_with(@post, request.referer)`

Then I had to make sure I had `add.js.erb` in my app/views/post, and in the js render the partial like `render :partial => 'public/post, :object => @post`